# python firebase slow response

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, raspberry-pi

i'm trying make smarthome software using raspberry Pi, and i used firebase for my database, i've tried and it work, but why it took time so long (arround 10 -30 second for turn on/off light) i try push button on/off from my website control, and i saw in firebase changing value so fast (arround 1-2 second) but why it took slow for turn on/off on my hardware. here my code (main.py)

```html
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import signal
import dht11
import socket
import time
import datetime
import os
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from gpiozero import LED
from clases.Connection import Connection
from firebase import firebase
from time import sleep

#firebase
fire = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://21324.firebaseio.com', None)

#initialization GPIO port
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.cleanup()


garage = LED(17)
livingroom = LED(27)
familyroom = LED(22)
bedroom2 = LED(18)
bedroom1 = LED(23)
kitchen = LED(24)
bathroom = LED(5)
backyard = LED(6)
waterpump = LED(13)
fan = LED(19)



##Date time formatting
dateString = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'

def lastupdate():
 updated = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime(dateString))

 return(updated)
 fire.put("/Settings", "/last_update_datetime", datetime.datetime.now().strftime(dateString))


#pin temperature
instance = dht11.DHT11(pin=21)
result = instance.read()

def readdht11():
 if result.is_valid():
  #temperature = ("Temperature: %d C" % result.temperature)
  #humidity = ("Humidity: %d %%" % result.humidity)

  temperature = ('%d' % result.temperature)
  humidity = ('%d' % result.humidity)

  return(temperature, humidity)

def process(value_garage, value_livingroom, value_familyroom, value_bedroom1, value_bedroom2, value_kitchen, value_bathroom, value_backyard, value_waterpump, value_fan, result):

 print("=======================================")
 print(lastupdate())
 print("Temp | Humid")
 print(readdht11())
 print("CPU temp: "+getCPUtemperature())
 print("CPU used:"+getCPUuse())
 print("RAM info:")
 print(getRAMinfo())
 print("Disk space:")
 print(getDiskSpace())
 
  
 if value_garage:
  garage.on()
  print ("garage on")
 else:
  garage.off()
  print ("garage off")

 if value_livingroom:
  livingroom.on()
  print ("livingroom on")
 else:
  livingroom.off()
  print ("livingroom off")

 if value_familyroom:
  familyroom.on()
  print ("familyroom on")
 else:
  familyroom.off()
  print ("familyroom off")

 if value_bedroom2:
  bedroom2.on()
  print ("bedroom2 on")
 else:
  bedroom2.off()
  print ("bedroom2 off")

 if value_bedroom1:
  bedroom1.on()
  print ("bedroom1 on")
 else:
  bedroom1.off()
  print ("bedroom1 off")

 if value_kitchen:
  kitchen.on()
  print ("kitchen on")
 else:
  kitchen.off()
  print ("kitchen off")

 if value_bathroom:
  bathroom.on()
  print ("bathroom on")
 else:
  kitchen.off()
  print ("bathroom off")

 if value_backyard:
  backyard.on()
  print ("backyard on")
 else:
  backyard.off()
  print ("backyard off")

 if value_waterpump:
  waterpump.on()
  print ("waterpump on")
 else:
  waterpump.off()
  print ("waterpump off")

 if value_fan:
  fan.on()
  print ("fan on")
 else:
  fan.off()
  print ("fan off")



def getCPUtemperature():
    res = os.popen('vcgencmd measure_temp').readline()
    return(res.replace("temp=","").replace("'C\n",""))

def getRAMinfo():
    p = os.popen('free')
    i = 0
    while 1:
        i = i + 1
        line = p.readline()
        if i==2:
            return(line.split()[1:4])

# Return % of CPU used by user as a character string                                
def getCPUuse():
    return(str(os.popen("top -n1 | awk '/Cpu\(s\):/ {print $2}'").readline().strip(\
)))


def getDiskSpace():
    p = os.popen("df -h /")
    i = 0
    while 1:
        i = i +1
        line = p.readline()
        if i==2:
            return(line.split()[1:5])

def updateinfo():
 print("## Updating Firebase Info.. ##")
 fire.put("/Settings", "/last_update_datetime", datetime.datetime.now().strftime(dateString))

 #retrive max & min humidity (remove the %)
 maxHumidity = fire.get("/Controls/Sensors/Humidity/max_inside", None)
 maxHumidity = maxHumidity[:-1]

 minHumidity = fire.get("/Controls/Sensors/Humidity/min_inside", None)
 minHumidity = minHumidity[:-1]

 #retrieve max & min temperature (remove the C)
 #maxTemperature = fire.get("/Controls/Sensors/Temperature/max_inside", None)
 #maxTemperature = maxTemperature[:-1]

 #minTemperature = fire.get("/Controls/Sensors/Temperature/min_inside", None)
 #minTemperature = minTemperature[:-1]

  #add current value
 temperature, humidity = readdht11()
 #fire.put("/Controls/Sensors", "/Humidity/current_inside", ""+humidity+"%")
 #fire.put("/Controls/Sensors", "/Temperature/current_inside", ""+temperature+"C")

 #check for max values
 #if float(humidity) > float(maxHumidity):
 # fire.put("/Controls/Sensors", "/Humidity/max_inside", ""+humidity+"%")
 # print("Updated Humidity max_inside")
 #if float(temperature) > float(maxTemperature):
 # fire.put("/Controls/Sensors", "/Temperature/max_inside", ""+temperature+"C")
 # print("Updated Temperature max_inside")

 # check for min values
 #if float(humidity) < float(minHumidity):
 # fire.put("/Controls/Sensors", "/Humidity/min_inside", ""+humidity+"%")
 # print("Updated Humidity min_inside")
 #if float(temperature) < float(minTemperature):
 # fire.put("/Controls/Sensors", "/Temperature/min_inside", ""+temperature+"C")
 # print("Updated Temperature min_inside")


 #CPU INFO
 CPU_temp = getCPUtemperature()
 CPU_usage = getCPUuse()
 fire.put("/PI/CPU", "/temperature", CPU_temp)

 #RAM INFO
 RAM_stats = getRAMinfo()
 RAM_total = round(int(RAM_stats[0]) / 1000,1)
 RAM_used = round(int(RAM_stats[1]) / 1000,1)
 RAM_free = round(int(RAM_stats[2]) / 1000,1)
 fire.put("/PI/RAM", "/free", str(RAM_free)+"")
 fire.put("/PI/RAM", "/used", str(RAM_used)+"")
 fire.put("/PI/RAM", "/total", str(RAM_total)+"")

 #DISK INFO
 DISK_stats = getDiskSpace()
 DISK_total = DISK_stats[0]
 DISK_free = DISK_stats[2]
 DISK_perc = DISK_stats[3]
 DISK_used = float(DISK_total[:-1]) - float(DISK_free[:-1])
 fire.put("/PI/DISK", "/total", str(DISK_total[:-1]))
 fire.put("/PI/DISK", "/free", str(DISK_free[:-1]))
 fire.put("/PI/DISK", "/used", str(DISK_used))
 fire.put("/PI/DISK", "/percentage", str(DISK_perc))

 print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime(dateString))
 #print("Temperature: Current["+temperature+"], Max["+maxTemperature+"], Min["+minTemperature+"]")
 print("Humidity: Current["+humidity+"], Max["+maxHumidity+"], Min["+minHumidity+"]")
 print("CPU temperature: "+CPU_temp)
 print("RAM total["+str(RAM_total)+" MB], RAM used["+str(RAM_used)+" MB], RAM free["+str(RAM_free)+" MB]")
 print("DISK total["+str(DISK_total)+"], free["+str(DISK_free)+"], perc["+str(DISK_perc)+"]")
 print("## Update finished successfully ##")
 print("======================================================\n")

sys.stdout.flush()

while True:
 try:
  ##print ("Start")
  
  print("")
 ## sleepTime = 500#fire.get("/Settings/info_update_time_interval", None)
 ## sleepTime = int(sleepTime)
 ## sleep(sleepTime)
 # updateinfo() #old
  t = Connection(process) #old
  t.daemon=True #old
  t.start() #old
  signal.pause() #old
 except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit): #old
  continue
 # raise #old
  #print ("output") #old
```

and this (Connection.py)

```html
from requests import ConnectionError
import requests
from firebase import firebase
import threading
import time


class Connection(threading.Thread):

 def __init__(self, cb):
  threading.Thread.__init__(self)
  self.callback = cb
  self.fire = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://213214.firebaseio.com/', None)
  self.status_garage = self.fire.get('/lights/garage', None)
  self.status_livingroom = self.fire.get('/lights/livingroom', None)
  self.status_familyroom = self.fire.get('/lights/familyroom', None)
  self.status_bedroom2 = self.fire.get('/lights/bedroom2', None)
  self.status_bedroom1 = self.fire.get('/lights/bedroom1', None)
  self.status_kitchen = self.fire.get('/lights/kitchen', None)
  self.status_bathroom = self.fire.get('/lights/bathroom', None)
  self.status_backyard = self.fire.get('/lights/backyard', None)
  self.status_waterpump = self.fire.get('/devices/waterpump', None)
  self.status_fan = self.fire.get('/devices/fan', None)
  self.status_result = self.fire.get('/lampu/result', None)

  #self.date = self.fire.get('/status/date', None)
  #self.humidity = self.fire.get('/status/humidity', None)
  #self.temperature = self.fire.get('/status/temperature', None)

  self.callback(self.status_garage, self.status_livingroom, self.status_familyroom, self.status_bedroom2, self.status_bedroom1, self.status_kitchen, self.status_bathroom, self.status_backyard, self.status_waterpump, self.status_fan, self.status_result)

 def run(self):
  SG = []
  SG.append(self.status_garage)

  SLR = []
  SLR.append(self.status_livingroom)

  SFR = []
  SFR.append(self.status_familyroom)

  SB2 = []
  SB2.append(self.status_bedroom2)

  SB1 = []
  SB1.append(self.status_bedroom1)

  SK = []
  SK.append(self.status_kitchen)

  SB = []
  SB.append(self.status_bathroom)

  SBA = []
  SBA.append(self.status_backyard)

  SWP = []
  SWP.append(self.status_waterpump)

  SF = []
  SF.append(self.status_fan)

  SR = []
  SR.append(self.status_result)
  i = 0
  
  while True:
   status_terkini_garage = self.fire.get('/lights/garage/garage', None)
   SG.append(status_terkini_garage)

   status_terkini_livingroom = self.fire.get('/lights/livingroom/livingroom', None)
   SLR.append(status_terkini_livingroom)

   status_terkini_familyroom = self.fire.get('/lights/familyroom/familyroom', None)
   SFR.append(status_terkini_familyroom)

   status_terkini_bedroom2 = self.fire.get('/lights/bedroom2/bedroom2', None)
   SB2.append(status_terkini_bedroom2)

   status_terkini_bedroom1 = self.fire.get('/lights/bedroom1/bedroom1', None)
   SB1.append(status_terkini_bedroom1)

   status_terkini_kitchen = self.fire.get('/lights/kitchen/kitchen', None)
   SK.append(status_terkini_kitchen)

   status_terkini_bathroom = self.fire.get('/lights/bathroom/bathroom', None)
   SB.append(status_terkini_bathroom)

   status_terkini_backyard = self.fire.get('/lights/backyard/backyard', None)
   SBA.append(status_terkini_backyard)

   status_terkini_waterpump = self.fire.get('/devices/waterpump/waterpump', None)
   SWP.append(status_terkini_waterpump)

   status_terkini_fan = self.fire.get('/devices/fan/fan', None)
   SF.append(status_terkini_fan)

   status_terkini_result = self.fire.get('/lights/result/result', None)
   SR.append(status_terkini_result)



   if SG[i] != SG[-1]:
    self.callback(status_terkini_garage, status_terkini_livingroom, status_terkini_familyroom, status_terkini_bedroom2,
     status_terkini_bedroom1, status_terkini_kitchen, status_terkini_bathroom, status_terkini_backyard, status_terkini_waterpump, status_terkini_fan, status_terkini_result)

   del SG[0]

   if SLR[i] != SLR[-1]:
    self.callback(status_terkini_garage, status_terkini_livingroom, status_terkini_familyroom, status_terkini_bedroom2,
     status_terkini_bedroom1, status_terkini_kitchen, status_terkini_bathroom, status_terkini_backyard, status_terkini_waterpump, status_terkini_fan, status_terkini_result)

   del SLR[0]

   if SFR[i] != SFR[-1]:
    self.callback(status_terkini_garage, status_terkini_livingroom, status_terkini_familyroom, status_terkini_bedroom2,
     status_terkini_bedroom1, status_terkini_kitchen, status_terkini_bathroom, status_terkini_backyard, status_terkini_waterpump, status_terkini_fan, status_terkini_result)

   del SFR[0]

   if SB2[i] != SB2[-1]:
    self.callback(status_terkini_garage, status_terkini_livingroom, status_terkini_familyroom, status_terkini_bedroom2,
     status_terkini_bedroom1, status_terkini_kitchen, status_terkini_bathroom, status_terkini_backyard, status_terkini_waterpump, status_terkini_fan, status_terkini_result)

   del SB2[0]

   if SB1[i] != SB1[-1]:
    self.callback(status_terkini_garage, status_terkini_livingroom, status_terkini_familyroom, status_terkini_bedroom2,
     status_terkini_bedroom1, status_terkini_kitchen, status_terkini_bathroom, status_terkini_backyard, status_terkini_waterpump, status_terkini_fan, status_terkini_result)

   del SB1[0]

   if SK[i] != SK[-1]:
    self.callback(status_terkini_garage, status_terkini_livingroom, status_terkini_familyroom, status_terkini_bedroom2,
     status_terkini_bedroom1, status_terkini_kitchen, status_terkini_bathroom, status_terkini_backyard, status_terkini_waterpump, status_terkini_fan, status_terkini_result)

   del SK[0]

   if SB[i] != SB[-1]:
    self.callback(status_terkini_garage, status_terkini_livingroom, status_terkini_familyroom, status_terkini_bedroom2,
     status_terkini_bedroom1, status_terkini_kitchen, status_terkini_bathroom, status_terkini_backyard, status_terkini_waterpump, status_terkini_fan, status_terkini_result)

   del SB[0]

   if SBA[i] != SBA[-1]:
    self.callback(status_terkini_garage, status_terkini_livingroom, status_terkini_familyroom, status_terkini_bedroom2,
     status_terkini_bedroom1, status_terkini_kitchen, status_terkini_bathroom, status_terkini_backyard, status_terkini_waterpump, status_terkini_fan, status_terkini_result)

   del SBA[0]

   if SWP[i] != SWP[-1]:
    self.callback(status_terkini_garage, status_terkini_livingroom, status_terkini_familyroom, status_terkini_bedroom2,
     status_terkini_bedroom1, status_terkini_kitchen, status_terkini_bathroom, status_terkini_backyard, status_terkini_waterpump, status_terkini_fan, status_terkini_result)

   del SWP[0]

   if SF[i] != SF[-1]:
    self.callback(status_terkini_garage, status_terkini_livingroom, status_terkini_familyroom, status_terkini_bedroom2,
     status_terkini_bedroom1, status_terkini_kitchen, status_terkini_bathroom, status_terkini_backyard, status_terkini_waterpump, status_terkini_fan, status_terkini_result)

   del SF[0]

   

   i = i+i
   time.sleep(0.1)
```

can someone help me please :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I figured out that for some reason the first operation (either write or read) firebase takes a long time to respond.Maybe it is due to authentication or something.

I would recoment trying a "dummy" read from the database to "initialize it" and then go on with your main logic. All subsequent operations with firebase should happen instantaneously.

Let me know if it helps.